# How to set component between two components in aem?

Tags: aem

How can I set possibility for component to setting just after one special component?
I have a component, which should be just after title component, I had some thoughts to add parsys component under title component, and add possibility to that parsys to keep just one my component, but I am still getting such fail with setting component just after title. What possible resolutions can be of my problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the components in the template node? On a page, we can always drap and order the components as our need. If you are using API there are options where you can set it exactly at the right place. Could you please provide more insight on your requirement on how are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cq:template node to define this.

Which is explained clearly in http://www.sgaemsolutions.com/2018/02/cqtemplate-and-cqtemplatepath.html

Thanks to SG